# Is it possible to implement header-only non-template class?

Tags: c++, static, namespaces

As far as I understand standard, the only way to implement something non-template and non-inline in header without violating One Definition Rule, is to implement this is anonymous namespace.

But I'm unsure what happens with static variables in such class methods implementation:

```
// MyHeader.h
// ... pragma once, defines, etc. ...

// (anonymous namespace removed due to suggestions below)
// namespace
// {
    class A // a simplified single-threaded kind of Singleton
    { 
        // ... some private not static data ...
    public:
        static A& instance() 
        {
            static A instance;   // is it guaranteed to be module-global?
            return instance;
        }

        void doNothing();
    }

    // inline added as suggested in answers below
    // actually, I disabled inline in compile settings,
    // checked that inlining was not happened using disassembler, 
    // but `inline` keyword is needed and it matters. Any suggestions, why?
    inline void A::doNothing()
    {
        // it's a very long method, so long that I don't want to 
        // implement it as inline within class body.

        // but not so long to consider refactoring it to smaller functions :)
    }        
//}

// File executable_part1.cpp
// ... includes, etc. ....
A::instance().doNothing();

// File executable_part2.cpp
// ... includes, etc. ....
A::instance().doNothing();
```

The main questions are:

- Is it guaranteed that `instance` is module-global?
- Is this portable code or behavior is compiler implementation-defined?

I have experimented with this code on MSVS 2012 on Windows. I have included this header in 2 .cpp-files for each of 3 modules: one executable and 2 dlls, loaded by executable. 6 times overall.

Without namespace: constuctor was called 3 times, once for each 'OS-level' module.
With namespace: constuctor was called 6 times, once for each cpp file.

UPDATE:
As pointed below, chapter 7.1.2 of C++'03 standard solves my question. Inline matters here.

Comment: Your first assertion is incorrect. Consider the `inline` keyword.

Comment: Why incorrect and why inline matters? Isn't members, declared inside class declaration "inlined" automatically? AFAIR, they is.

Comment: No, only if it is *defined* inside the class. The point is you can implement something non-template in a header without an anonymous namespace.

Comment: I'm sorry, but actually I made a misspell, it's already defined inside.

Comment: I have just added sample to my code. Thank you for note.

Comment: So, look into the `inline` keyword.

Comment: The way you have it implemented now, wherever you include that header, a new struct definition for A will be available to that compilation unit. Different classes means different singletons

Comment: juanchopanza, is there any proof that if I add `inline` to both functions in my sample, `instance` will be shared in all files including my header?

Comment: To сppguy: yes, this is what I'm afraid of. So, how do you think, it is possible to leave it non-template and header-only?

Comment: @Victor: removing the anonymous namespace will prevent that. Also, move doNothing to a cpp file. Unless you have a really good reason for exposing implementation details in the header, you're probably not gaining anything.

Comment: @cppguy: I have a really good reason to put it in header, thanks.

Comment: Remember, header bloat = slower compiling

Comment: Is there any good answer here as to what `inline` *actually* means? If anything? Once we get over that it doesn't actually cause or allow inlining? It allows multiple definitions (i.e the linker won't complain)? {The definitions must be identical of course}. All template methods are `inline` by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use unnamed namespace as each translation unit will have its own struct A.

just do

```
class A
{ 
    // ... some private not static data ...
public:
    static A& instance() 
    {
        static A instance;
        return instance;
    }

    void doNothing();
};

inline void A::doNothing()
{
    // it's a very long method, so long that I don't want to 
    // implement it as inline within class body.

    // but not so long to consider refactoring it to smaller functions :)
}
```

- It is normal that the singleton are not shared between exe/dll.
- with unnamed namespace you have singleton for each TU, whereas without it, the singleton is shared for the whole exe (and respectively for the whole Dll).

For your configuration: 1 exe with 2 cpp, and 2 Dll with both 2 cpp:
your experiment is correct: 6 with unnamed namespace, and 3 without it.

Comment: Yep! And this works even if inlining is disabled in compiler settings, so even if `inline` was ignored by compiler. Can you explain, why? Without `inline` it produced errors.

Comment: Thank you. As about not sharing between .exe and .dll I agree, it's normal and it's by class design. The only opened questions for me, it **why this code works with `inline` even when inlining disabled?**, and **is it compiler-dependent code?** Additionally, I checked that inlining was not actually happened in disassembler.

Comment: The fact that compiler inline really the code or not is independent. And it is not compiler-specific.

Comment: Got it, thanks. Just found the proof: in '03 standard (ISO/IEC 14882:2003), chapter 7.1.4: `An inline function shall be defined in every translation unit in which it is used and shall have exactly the same definition in every case (3.2). ...(cut text)... An inline
function with external linkage shall have the same address in all translation units. A static local variable in an extern inline
function always refers to the same object. A string literal in an
extern inline function is the same object in different translation units.`

Answer (score -1):

I really didn´t understand well the question (maybe I missed something ) so keep what you need.

To my understanding, static methods and data, pertain to the class itself and not to the instances of the class.
So static data exist just once and are the same independently if these are accessed from different objects.
Static methods are like normal external functions and no `this` pointer is available to them.
Belong to the namespace of the class so every class could implement a static function with the same name, and there would be no name clash because their names are not equal because the fully qualified name is: "classOfAppartenence::nameOfFunction" and the fully qualified name is different for each of them.
Essentially if you don't implement any object for the class, the class works as just a namespace.

Comment: The main question is: **Is it guaranteed that A::instance() call provides access to the same object when it's called from several cpp files?**


Actually, on Visual C++ it is the same object, but I haven't found any proof that this code is portable and stable. And no proof that it is not.

Comment: _"I really didn´t understood well the question"_ That claims for a commment, rather than an answer!

Comment: Semantically to my understanding, static variables are just global variables defined in the namespace of the Class. So if across different files a global variable would be seen as the same, then the same would happen too for "global variables" in the namespace of a class. And conversely if for some reason, the global wouldn't be seen as the same than the same is true for the "global of a class".

Comment: Copying from wikipedia: "In any translation unit, a template, type, function, or object can have no more than one definition. Some of these can have any number of declarations. A definition provides an instance."
"In the entire program, an object or non-inline function cannot have more than one definition;"   The last phrase means that an object as a static variable of a Class should have only one definition.

Comment: So your question addresses an incoherence, where there could exist two different classes with the same name accross different compilation units, and these should be treated as different. In that case the classes have the same name but are different, so their static variables are different too between them. What is your experience about that ?

Comment: I didn't fully understand your comment. Basically, I'm agree, but I'm unsure if inline-functions containing static variable will address the same static variable in different translation unit. Additionally, I'm not sure if "not-inlined" function which declared as `inline` will not make linker errors.

Comment: To my understanding the only difference of inline functions is that these do not have any name exposed to be used from the linker. So what happens with normal functions happens also for inline functions, but you may have two different inline functions with the same name in two different compilation units and because of non exposition of that name these do not clash.

Comment: So what is addressed from inline functions is exactly what addressed from a normal function. A normal function when accesses the static variables of a class sees the "local" class of it's compilation unit, so has no way to see the "other" class in the other compilation unit. The logic behind is that classes and types and templates exist only during compilation so when compilation is over nothing exists. Instead objects and functions are "data" left behind by compilation so these are accessible from any compilation unit. Please take into account that what I say is from my mind so double check!